# Show all the posts of the pages that the user follow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, data-structures

I want to present all the posts ,of the pages, which the user follow. I have table "followings" with the fields "user_id" and "page_id"( for example user_id=100, and page_id=120, & user_id=100 and page_id=130...)

This is how I print all the pages that the user follow

```
    $que_following=mysql_query("select * from followings where user_id='$user_id'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($que_following)) 
    {
        echo $row['page_id'];
    }
```

And this is how I get all the posts, from "user_post"

```
$posts=mysql_query("select * from posts order by post_id desc");
```

Now I want to get all the posts from the pages that the user follow, I thought of something like that:

```
$posts=mysql_query("select * from posts where page_id=120 OR page_id=130 OR...... order by post_id desc");
```

But how can I do that?

Comment: Keyword is `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple inner join to get all "followings" associated for a specified user id. Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   posts
      INNER JOIN followings ON posts.id = followings.page_id;
```